# How to write set cover code by using Lisp ? (algorithm is included)

Tags: list, set, lisp, common-lisp

I have the problem about writing a set cover problem code by using Common Lisp.

`(setcover N S)`, `N` is a nonnegative integer, and `S` is a set of subsets of the numbers U = (1 2 ... N). The set cover problem asks to find a (small) number of subsets in S such that their union covers U. This means that every number in U is contained in at least one of the subsets in the solution. And the final solution has to be greedy

ex:

```
(let ((S '((1 2 3) (2 4) (3 4) (2 5) (4 5))))
  (setcover 5 S))
```

output :

```
((1 2 3) (4 5))
```

I tried to write this code, and I did write the algorithm for it.
(round means recursion)

first round:
 use number function to create a list (1 ,2 ....U)
 then use common function to compare the sublist of S and list U and check how many numbers are in common. then take that sublist for construction(in this ex, it is (1 2 3)), finally remove (1 2 3) from list U.

second round:
 check again, and there is only (4 5) left in list U, so sublist (4 5) will be used.

third round:
 nothing left, so a new list will be formed ((1 2 3) (4 5))

My problems are how to find the largest number from common function in each round? how to remove those matched numbers from list U (since it has to be created first) ? and how to create a new list at the end?

```
;create a list U
(defun numbers (N)  
  (if (<= N 0)
      nil
    (append (numbers (- N 1)) (list n))))

;check if this atom exist in the list
(defun check (Atom List)
  (cond
   ((null List) nil)
   ((equal Atom (car List)))
   (t (check Atom (cdr List)))))

;numbers of common numbers that both two lists have
(defun common (L1 L2)
  (cond 
   ((null L1) 0)
   ((check (car L1) L2) (+ 1 (common (cdr L1) L2)))
   (t (common (cdr L1) L2))))

;final setcover function but I have no idea what to do next...
(defun setcover (N S)
  (cond 
   ((if (null S) nil))
   ((listp (car S)) 
    (common (car S) (numbers N)) 
    (setcover N (cdr S)))))
```

Hope someone could help me. Thank you !

**2019/01/24 (more question descriptions)**

Write a Lisp function:

(setcover N S)
This function should implement the greedy algorithm for the set cover problem. This problem and the algorithm are described below. The Wikipedia article on set cover also explains the problem (in much more detail than we need).

In (setcover N S), N is a nonnegative integer, and S is a set of subsets of the numbers U = (1 2 ... N). The set cover problem asks to find a (small) number of subsets in S such that their union covers U. This means that every number in U is contained in at least one of the subsets in the solution.

Example:

```
(let
    ((S '((1 2 3) (2 4) (3 4) (2 5) (4 5))))
    (setcover 5 S)
)
```

A solution:

```
((1 2 3) (4 5))
```

Explanations: N = 5, so U = (1 2 3 4 5). S consists of some subsets of (1 2 3 4 5). We are looking for some small number of those subsets that together cover all the five numbers.

The best solution uses only two subsets, (1 2 3) and (4 5). Another solution, with three subsets, is ((1 2 3) (2 4) (2 5)). Yet another solution is ((1 2 3) (2 4) (3 4) (2 5)). However, in this solution you could remove either (2 4) or (3 4) and get a smaller solution that still covers all of U.

Solving the set cover problem optimally means to find the smallest number of subsets of S that cover U. (Number of sets, not size of sets.) Unfortunately, this problem is NP-hard, and therefore no efficient algorithm is known.

Instead of the optimal solution, your program should compute and return the greedy solution - a small set of subsets that covers U and is computed by the so-called greedy algorithm below. This algorithm is also described on the wikipedia page.

The basic idea is to solve the problem in several rounds. In each round, we select one more subset from S until we have a complete cover. We pick a subset that contains as many of the still missing numbers as possible.

Assume that we still have some of the numbers in (1 2 ... N) left to cover. We consider each subset Si in S, and count how many of these numbers would be covered by Si. Then we greedily pick a subset that covers the most.

DETAILED EXAMPLE

```
S = ((1 2 3) (2 4) (3 4) (2 5) (4 5))
Subsets in S: S1 = (1 2 3), S2 = (2 4), S3 = (3 4), S4 = (2 5), S5 = (4 5)
N = 5
U = (1 2 3 4 5)

Start of algorithm:
Solution so far = ()
Still to cover = (1 2 3 4 5)

Round 1:
Covered by S1: 3 numbers (1 2 3)
Covered by S2: 2 numbers (2 4)
Covered by S3: 2 numbers 
Covered by S4: 2
Covered by S5: 2
Best subset: S1, covers 3 numbers (1 2 3)
Solution so far = (S1)
Still to cover = (4 5)

Round 2:
Covered by S2: 1 number (4)
Covered by S3: 1 number (4)
Covered by S4: 1 number (5)
Covered by S5: 2 numbers (4 5)
Best: S5, covers (4 5)
Solution so far = (S1 S5)
Still to cover = ()

Round 3:
Nothing left to cover, so stop.
Return solution (S1 S5) = ((1 2 3) (4 5))
```

More example :

```
(setcover 2 '((1) (2) (1 2)))
((1 2))

(let
    ((S '((1 2 3 4 5))))
    (setcover 5 S)
)
((1 2 3 4 5))
```

Comment: i know my problem is a bit weird, but I am totally new to Lisp. I am still unfamiliar to this code ...

Comment: You're not doing anything with the return value of `common`.

Comment: You're also not combining the results of each recursion with the previous level to produce the complete results.

Comment: @Barmar cuz set over function is complete wrong atm . It won't return anything, I just don't know how to write it .

Comment: What do you mean by the final solution being greedy? I would have expected a greedy algorithm to come up with the solution `((1 2 3) (2 4) (2 5))` to your example (by picking every sublist that contains at least one new number).

Comment: Common Lisp has built-in functions `SET-DIFFERENCE` and `SET-INTERSECTION`. These would probably be useful for you. E.g. `(common s1 s2)` is just `(length (set-intersection s1 s2))`.

Comment: @Barmar my prof only allows us to use some specific built-in functions. set-difference/set-intersection are both not allowed :(

Comment: @jkiiski greedy solution will just be ((1 2 3) (4 5)).

Comment: @CodeVanessa You need to explain what you mean by "greedy". Why is that greedier than his suggested answer? Does it also have to minimize duplication (he has three instances of `2`).

Comment: @Barmar uh... so ((1 2 3) ( 4 5)) is greediest because it has the smallest set of subsets. Duplication is not necessary, this function will find (1 2 3) sublist first, then it will look for the rest subsets (4 5).

Comment: That's not what greedy usually means. Think about what greedy means with regular expressions -- it tries to consume as much of the input string as possible. I think what you really mean is "minimal", the exact opposite of greedy.

Comment: @Barmar you're right, the result is much like a minimal result instead of a greedy result...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a possible greedy solution, with the hypothesis that all sets are sorted and without using the primitive functions of Common Lisp, like `set-difference`, and using only recursion (and not iteration or high-order functions).

```
(defun my-difference (s1 s2)
  "Compute the difference between set s1 and set s2"
  (cond ((null s1) nil)
        ((check (car s1) s2) (my-difference (cdr s1) s2))
        (t (cons (car s1) (my-difference (cdr s1) s2)))))

(defun cover-sets (s1 s2)
  "Compute the greedy cover of set s1 by elements of list of sets s2"
  (cond ((null s1) nil)
        ((null s2) (error "no cover possible"))
        (t (let ((diff (my-difference s1 (car s2))))
             (if (equal diff s1)
                 (cover-sets s1 (cdr s2))
                 (cons (car s2) (cover-sets diff (cdr s2))))))))

(defun setcover (n s)
  "Solve the problem"
  (cover-sets (numbers n) s))
```

Here is an alternative solution with primitive functions and iteration:

```
(defun cover (n s)
  (let ((u (loop for i from 1 to n collect i)))
    (loop for x in s
      for w = (intersection u x)
      when w
        do (setf u (set-difference u x))
        and collect x
      end
      while u)))
```

**Addition**

After the update of the post with the specification of the algorithm, here is a possible solution (without using recursion):

```
(defun count-common-elements (s1 s2)
  "return the number of common elements with s1 of each set of s2"
  (mapcar (lambda (x) (length (intersection s1 x))) s2))

(defun index-of-maximum (l)
  "return the index of the maximum element in list l"
  (position (reduce #'max l) l))

(defun setcover (n s)
  (let ((working-set (numbers n))
        (solution nil))
    (loop while working-set
          for i = (index-of-maximum (count-common-elements working-set s))
          for set = (elt s i)
          do (setf working-set (set-difference working-set set)
                   s (remove set s))
          do (push set solution))
   (reverse solution)))
```

and here is a recursive solution:

```
(defun most-elements (s1 s2 m)
  "find the set with the higher number of elements in common 
 with s1 between m and all the elements of s2"
  (if (null s2)
      m
      (let ((l1 (length (my-difference s1 m)))
            (l2 (length (my-difference s1 (car s2)))))
        (if (< l1 l2)
            (most-elements s1 (cdr s2) m)
            (most-elements s1 (cdr s2) (car s2))))))     

(defun greedy-cover-set (s1 s2)
  "find the greedy cover set of s1 by using the sets elements of s2"
  (cond ((null s1) nil)
        ((null s2) (error "no cover possible"))
        (t (let ((candidate (most-elements s1 s2 nil)))
            (cons
              candidate
              (greedy-cover-set (my-difference s1 candidate)
                                (remove candidate s2)))))))

(defun setcover (n s)
  (greedy-cover-set (numbers n) s))
```

Note that `remove` is the predefined function of Common Lisp (see the [manual](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_rm_rm.htm#remove)). It is not difficult to give a recursive definition of it.

Comment: Sorry, if i put (let
    ((S '((1 2 3 4 5))))
    (setcover 5 S)
) the output is ((1 2 3) (2 4) (2 5))
but what I really want is ((1 2 3) (4 5)), how am I supposed to change the code so that it will just find the minimal subsets for me ? Thank you!

Comment: You asked for a greedy solution. In general greedy means: “stop searching as soon as any solution is found”. If you need a really minimal solution then the program must be more complex. Do you need the minimal possible solution? Or an “intermediate” solution? Do you have a description of the problem? I’ll try to post a different solution later.

Comment: I updated this problem description, but not sure why this question uses 'greedy' to describe the desired result. It should just tell us that we need to find minimal subsets...

Comment: @CodeVanessa, ok, I've read the specification and will implement that algorithm. Do you need to use only recursion or also iteration and all Common Lisp functions?

Comment: It would be my pleasure to have both. Thank you for your help again!

Comment: @CodeVanessa, I added a new function to the answer. Now its very late for me, so   I will try tomorrow to add a recursive function.

Comment: Sure, could not wait your recursive function!

Comment: I read your solution, it is clear and easy to understand. Thank you again for your help!

Comment: You are wellcome.